# How to get values from foreach with insert statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, foreach

I'm a newbie. I use `GetSelectedIndices` and `foreach` to get each values in array.

After that, I provided those values for the insert statement. How can I get query_TheLoai from insert statement in foreach? I work it on webform

```
var TheLoaiIds = lbxTheLoai.GetSelectedIndices();

foreach (var TheLoaiId in TheLoaiIds)
{
    string query_TheLoai = "SELECT @MaPhim = SCOPE_IDENTITY();INSERT INTO ChiTietTL VALUES ('" + TheLoaiId + "', @MaPhim)";
}
```

Sorry for the awkwardness

Comment: Consider using an ORM like entity framework or dapper for your routine/mundane database operations like this

Answer (score 0):

```
var TheLoaiIds = lbxTheLoai.GetSelectedIndices();
string CStr = "YourConnectionString";

string Query = "INSERT INTO ChiTietTL VALUES ('" + TheLoaiId + "', @MaPhim)";

using(var conn = new SqlConnection(CStr))
{
    foreach (var TheLoaiId in TheLoaiIds)
    {
        using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, conn))
        {
             try
             {
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaPhim", TheLoaiId);
                 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
             }
             catch (SqlException ex)
             {
                 MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: `"INSERT INTO ChiTietTL VALUES ('" + TheLoaiId + "', @MaPhim)";`. `TheLoaiId` outside foreach so it is errored

Answer (score 0):

```
    var TheLoaiIds = lbxTheLoai.GetSelectedIndices();
    string CStr = "YourConnectionString";

    string Query = "SELECT @MaPhim = SCOPE_IDENTITY(); INSERT INTO ChiTietTL VALUES (@TheLoaiId, @MaPhim)";

    using(var conn = new SqlConnection(CStr))
    {
        foreach (var TheLoaiId in TheLoaiIds)
        {
            using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, conn))
            {
                 try
                 {
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TheLoaiId", TheLoaiId);
                     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 }
                 catch (SqlException ex)
                 {
                     MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                 }
             }
         }

}
```